# Ability to pull Excel into Salesforce

Tags: appexchange, excel

Is it possible to display reports which is in excel same ways in salesforce.

I know that there are some apps available on appexchange but can you guide me some of them which would fit my requirement.

Regards

Comment: So you want to display in a SFDC page an Excel worksheet w pivot tables and charts?

Answer (score 1):

You can export the report from Salesforce this is native functionality. Salesforce did have a plugin for excel which allowed you to directly download a report into Salesforce but I don't think it's available anymore. Apttus have can app called X-author that does a similar thing but also allows you to edit rows in Excel and sync them back to Salesforce.

Comment: Do we have an option to display same reports which is in excel in salesforce

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for VF page to be displayed as Excel file, then try the sample code below.

```
<apex:page controller="Contactquery" contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#SalesForceExport.xls" cache="true">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Export Results" >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cs}" var="contact">
            <apex:column value="{!contact.ID}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!contact.Name}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>



public class Contactquery{
    public List<Contact> cs{get; set;}
    public contactquery()
    {
    cs = new List<Contact>();
       for (Contact c : [Select id, Name from Contact])
       {       
           cs.add(c);
       }
    }
}
```

Referenced link is, https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003176

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Use field sets too then the admins can declaratively change the fields in the report.